# Android tablet I2C Read Errors

Tags: charging, hardware

i've a brand new Ramos i9 tablet and have big issues with the touchscreen and charging. I've rooted it, and before i send it in for repair, i'm trying to debug the issue (in hope it's only software).

If the tablet is fully charged, the touchscreen and battery information is working fine. But after a discharge to 50% leads to the failure of the touchscreen and battery information. It somehow recharges after 1 day to 95%, and then everything works again.

If i'm under 95% (and the system was rebooted), i get these i2c errors at boot time:

```
<6>[    1.454126] ==ft5x0x_ts_probe=
<6>[    1.624056] input: ft5x0x_ts as /devices/virtual/input/input0
<3>[    1.783786] i2c-designware-pci 0000:00:00.5: i2c_dw_handle_tx_abort: slave address not acknowledged (7bit mode) :slave add 0x38
<3>[    1.784019] ft5x0x_ts 2-0038: fft5x0x_i2c_Read: i2c read error.
<6>[    1.784137] ft5x0x_ts 2-0038: [FTS] Firmware version = 0x71
...
<3>[    1.795292] max170xx_battery 2-0036: I2C SMbus Read error:-121
<4>[    1.795413] max170xx_battery 2-0036: reset i2c device:-121
...
<4>[   34.364528] smb347 2-006a: failed to read reg 0x30: -110
<4>[   34.364642] smb347 2-006a: smb347 suspend
<4>[   34.411268] smb347: probe of 2-006a failed with error -110
```

The ft5x0x_ts module is for touchscreen, the max170xx and smb347 for battery information and charging.

If the system is running, the touchscreen does not react to movements, but the kernel log flashes when i'm touching the screen:

```
<3>[  787.510109] i2c-designware-pci 0000:00:00.5: i2c_dw_handle_tx_abort: slave address not acknowledged (7bit mode) :slave add 0x38
<3>[  787.510356] ft5x0x_ts 2-0038: fft5x0x_i2c_Read: i2c read error.
<3>[  787.510472] ft5x0x_ts 2-0038: ft5x0x_read_Touchdata read touchdata failed.
```

How can i pin down this issue? Could this be a thermal problem?

Maybe anyone has an idea how to proceed. Thanks!

Comment: It's too late for you, but in case any other visitors are thinking of doing this: if you have a brand new tablet, and it goes wrong like this, send it back straight away. Don't root it or try to fix the problem yourself: you'll probably void the warranty.